# How to Display percentage calculation for each screen on html page report

Tags: javascript, python, html

Need to generate a report in html page that contains summary of test cases. There are 30+ screens and I need to show the screen name and pass percentage of no.of test cases at the end of each screen name.I am using python and javascript along with html.

I tried the following code:

```
def screen_name(self,screenName):
        try:
            if(self.accord==0):
                self.htmlapp.write("<button class=\"accordion1\">"+screenName+ "<span id =\"Pass_Percentage\" style=\"float:right;color:#2E8B57\"> </span></button>")
                self.accord=1
                debug_report.log("HTMLModule", "screen_name", "INFO", "screenname is passed as an argument")
                #return screenName
            else:
                self.htmlapp.write("<button class=\"accordion2\">"+screenName+"<span id =\"Pass_Percentage\" style=\"float:right;color:#2E8B57\"> </span></button>")

                self.accord=0
                debug_report.log("HTMLModule", "screen_name", "INFO", "screenname is passed as an argument")
            return screenName
        except BaseException as Err:
            debug_report.log("HTMLModule", "screen_name", "Info", "exception in  screenname function")
            debug_report.log("HTMLModule", "screen_name", "Error Info", Err)
            return UNKNOWN_ERROR
```

### percentage calculation will be done and populated while ending the table

```
def resultstableend(self,):
        try:
            self.Pass_Percentage = int(self.pass_count * 100 / (self.pass_count + self.fails_count))
            print('pass=',self.pass_count,"\nfail=",self.fails_count,"\npass_percentage=",self.Pass_Percentage)
            self.htmlapp.write("<script>document.getElementById(\"Pass_Percentage\").innerText=\"" + str(self.Pass_Percentage) + "%""\";</script>")
            self.htmlapp.write("</table><br></div>")
            self.htmlapp.write("</div>")
        except BaseException as Err:
            debug_report.log("HTMLModule", "resultstableend", "Info", "exception in resultstableend function")
            debug_report.log("HTMLModule", "resultstableend", "Error Info", Err)
```

Expected Result:(Say)
SCREENNAME-1 100%
SCREENNAME-2 80%
Actual Result:
SCREENNAME-1 80%
SCREENNAME-2

In the second iteration, screenname-1 percentage is replaced with screenname-2 percentage and screenname-2 displays nothing.
I would be happy if some one guides me.